# Check if characters are duplicated in a string

Tags: c#

How can I check if character or number is used only once using C#?

Valid:

`abcdef`

Invalid:

`aabbccddeeff`

Example usage:

```
string stringToTest = "tteesstt0011";
if (OnlyOnceCheck(stringToTest))
{
    throw new Exception("Each character or number can be used only once");
}
```

Comment: have you made an attempt?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use LINQ:

```
public static bool OnlyOnceCheck(string input)
{
    return input.GroupBy(x => x).Any(g => g.Count() > 1);
}
```

or with `Distinct`:

```
public static bool OnlyOnceCheck(string input)
{
    return input.Distinct().Count() == input.Length;
}
```

**Update**

If someone is afraid about performance, you can always get a little better with `HasSet<char>`:

```
public static bool OnlyOnceCheck(string input)
{
    var set = new HashSet<char>();
    return input.Any(x => !set.Add(x));
}
```

or if you're afraid about delegate invocation overhead you can use `for` loop:

```
public static bool OnlyOnceCheck(string input)
{
    var set = new HashSet<char>();
    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        if (!set.Add(input[i]))
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

but `Any()` on `string` does exactly the same thing...

Comment: LINQ is awesome but inappropriate usage can be dangerous.

Comment: Geez, how much overhead does that one-liner produce?

Comment: @DavidRTribble You can measure it. But I would not be afraid of that. Although, I've added 2 more solutions, without LINQ.

Comment: `Distinct` uses internal `Set` (which is hash set) and in this case overhead is minimal. But with grouping it is .....

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a map (hashmap for example) with characters as keys and their occurrence as value. If any value is > 1 then the string is invalid. 
Or simply while adding the key to map, if it already exists, the string is invalid.

in C#:

```
    static bool OnlyOnceCheck(String str){
        Hashtable myHT = new Hashtable();
        for (int i=0; i<str.Length; i++){
            if (!myHT.ContainsKey(str[i])){
                myHT.Add(str[i],1);
            } else return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Sorry for my java like coding style, I have not used C# much.

Comment: Non-generic `Hashtable`? Boxing on every call? Really? I understand Java background, but you should be aware of differences between Java and C# when answering C# questions. .NET has much different generics than Java and not using it in cases like that is a huge mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Using Linq:

```
public static bool OnlyOnceCheck(string input)
{
    return input.Distinct().Count() == input.Length
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My contribution:

```
private bool OnlyOnceCheck(string value){
    if (value == null)
        return true;

    for(int i = 0; i < value.length; i++){
         if (value.LastIndexOf(value[i]) != i){
             return false;
         }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: It's clever, but the worse-case behavior for this algorithm is O(n^2). But for small strings, it may be the fastest way.

Comment: @AndréFigueiredo I think it's not. LINQ uses `HashSet<T>` for `Distinct` internally, and other *O(1)* lookup collection for `GroupBy`, so I would expect LINQ to be faster.

Answer (score 1):

And with a regex:

```
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch("abcde", @"(.).*\1")); // False
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch("abcce", @"(.).*\1")); // True
```

`(.)` matches and captures any character and `\1` finds another match for the same character.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ToCharArray()` method to convert your string into an Array of Characters and then loop through the values of the char `[] newStr` , using a counter to count occurrences of each Char . and `If ELse` statement to evaluate your result

```
char [] newStr = stringToTest.ToCharArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

The more efficient method is to scan the string, character by character from left to right, counting each occurrence of each character code. Once you hit a character that has already been counted, you can reject the whole string; otherwise the whole string gets scanned and each character in it only occurs once.

The real problem is determining how you are going to keep track of the character counts. If the string can contain any character codes (all 65,536 Unicode characters), then you are best off using a hash table of integer counts, indexed/keyed by character codes.

On the other hand, if you know that the string will only contain a fairly small subset of characters (say, the ISO 8859-1 Latin-1 codes from '\u0000' to '\u00FF'), then you can use a small integer array to hold the counters.

Answer (score 0):

Linq Query to find if any char has a duplicate:

```
var Duplicates = str.GroupBy(x => x).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Count()).Any(x => x.Value > 1);
```